# Get the exit code of a previous command in Python?

Tags: python, bash, shell

Is it possible to get the exit code of the previous command that as run on the shell in python?

I want to write a script that will return the same error code that is currently set (assuming the python command is successful). It would be the equivalent of doing something like this in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
err=$?

# Do something...

exit $err
```

I would like to avoid passing it in as an argument, if possible. For example:

```
python script.py $?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that your solution (wrapping both the "previous command" and the Python script in a shell script that keeps track of the return codes) is the way to go:

```
#!/bin/bash
first_command
ERR=$?
python second_script.py
exit $ERR
```

The Python script will be more reusable as it won't have to rely on any assumption about its environment.

Any reason why this wrap solution doesn't fit your case?

Comment: You need to export `ERR` as well; otherwise, it is just a shell variable, not an environment variable, and the python script will not have access to it.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it is not possible. A command started by bash has no access to the shell variables nor to the shell itself. It can only knows :

- all the variable present in environment (but $? is not)
- the pid of the shell and via it the path of the shell

But I do not know any bash API to get more.